# image is not showing in django templates am new in django and working on a project...i idid lots of rid of this error but nothing happen

Tags: python, django

am trying to show pic in django tempate but its not working

here is my settings.py where the path of static and media file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , "media")
```

this is my model.py
the image is store under static/img folder

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sending_item = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image_of_load = models.ImageField(default='',upload_to='static/img')
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    metric_unit = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pick_up_time = models.DateField()
    drop_time = models.DateField()
    paid_by = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

this is my html template for showing user posted data

```
{% extends "post.html" %}
 {% block content %}
{% load static %} 
{% for loader in Loader %}

                <h4>Loader Id- {{loader.id}}</h4> Username-{{user.username}}

                <h3>Sender name-{{loader.sender_name}}</h3>
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">
                <h4>pick up station-{{loader.pick_up_station}}</h4>
            </p>
            <img src="{{ loader.image.url }}" alt="image">
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.destination_station}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.phone_number}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.receiver_name}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.sending_item}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.weight}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.quantity}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.pick_up_time}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.drop_time}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.paid_by}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{loader.created_at}}</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Loader:Delete' loader.id %} ">delete</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Loader:Update' loader.id %} ">update</a>


</div> {% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'Loader'

urlpatterns = [
    path('post_detail/', views.Loader_post_view.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    path('post/', views.post.as_view(), name="post"),
    path('my_job/', views.Loader_post_list.as_view(), name="my_job"),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.Loader_post_delete.as_view(), name="Delete"),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.Loader_post_update.as_view(template_name="post_detail.html"), name="Update")
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

how can i remove this error or any bug in my code?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Take a closer look

---

First of all, you use different names. In the models.py the image attribute corresponds to **image_of_load**, whereas in your template the src is equal to **{{loader.image.url}}** not **{{loader.image_of_load.url}}**. Second, try to put **{% load static %}** at the very top of your file, which is an advice from the documentation, at least above the {% block content %} tag.

> I think that on the models.py file, you should use **upload_to='img'** because you have set your static folder directory. Remember that the uploaded images by users go to your media folder / URL, not your static folder. The static folder is for CSS files and images that you serve, such as your website's logo.

I hope that helps. Feel free to ask me any more questions!

Comment: i did all of things what u told me sir but its not working yet

Comment: I suggest you watch some basic tutorials about the ImageField, static and media directories on Youtube.